# Converting Array[(Double,Double)] to Seq[Seq[Double]]

Tags: arrays, scala, type-conversion, seq

I am fairly new to Scala and I have to use a function which takes as argument of type `Seq[Seq[Double]]`. However, my data has the type `Array[(Double,Double)]`.

I tried using `.toSeq` to convert the data, but that doesn't work.

Any fixes in this regard would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val input: Array[(Double, Double)] = ...
val output: Seq[Seq[Double]] = input.map { case (x, y) => Seq(x, y) }
```

Unfortunately, there is no generic way to type-safely convert a tuple to a list in the standard library. [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), however, does provide this functionality:

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

val input: Array[(Double, Double)] = ...
val output: Seq[Seq[Double]] = input.map(_.toList)
```

Shapeless is smart enough to compute a lowest upper bound in case your tuple contains components of different types:

```
val input: Array[(Double, Int)] = ...
// AnyVal is the closest type which both Double and Int are subtypes of
val output: Seq[Seq[AnyVal]] = input.map(_.toList)
```

Finally, there is a non-type-safe way to do this using only the standard library tools. You can rely on the fact that all tuples in Scala implement the [Product](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Product.html) trait and therefore are iterable as collections of `Any`:

```
val input: Array[(Double, Double)] = ...
val output: Seq[Seq[Double]] = input.map(_.productIterator.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]])
```

This is safe as long as you're careful, but it does require an explicit cast and it is more verbose.

If you have fixed-length tuples of relatively small size, then I'd say it is better to use the partial function-based approach. Otherwise, it is up to you, but I'd use shapeless because it is type safe, and I also use shapeless in many of my projects for other things as well, so it is kind of free for me :)